# UICollectionViewController Layout-to-Layout Navigation Transitions

Tags: ios, navigation, uicollectionview, transition

I am working on multiple `UICollectionViewController`s that all show the same contents with different layouts.

According to Apple's **CollectionViewTransition** sample application and Session 218 of WWDC 2013, `UICollectionViewController` has a property called `useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions` that basically handles navigation transitions by interpolating 'from' and 'to' collection view's layouts.

Let's assume that I have two `UICollectionViewControllers` called ***MasterCollectionViewController*** and ***DetailCollectionViewController***. When I push ***DetailCollectionViewController*** from ***MasterCollectionViewController***, layout is properly changed, but collection view still uses the data source declared in ***MasterCollectionViewController***.

This is a problem for me, because in each of `UICollectionViewController`s, I need to rearrange section/item configurations. A good example of what I am trying to do is Photos application on iOS 7. The first tab of this application has three view controllers: years, collections, and moments. These view controller all show the same contents: photos. What's different between each view controller is how photos are grouped in section. And section grouping is the responsibility of `UICollectionViewDataSource` which is an issue here.

If the behavior of `useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions` property that I am experiencing is a normal behavior, is there a way to achieve my goal in different approach?

Any help or comment would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm seeing the same behaviour and agree it is less than ideal.

The fundamental issue here is that the same `UICollectionView` instance is shared/passed between the two view controllers. I experimented with trying to change the delegate and datasource of the `UICollectionView` but ran into various problems.

In the end, the solution I ended up adopting was to make the master `UICollectionViewController` a delegate of the `UINavigationController`, implementing:

`– navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:`

...using this to switch a `controllerMode` property and then adding switch statements to `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` and `-collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` to provide the required behaviour in the mode. I also added code to `-setControllerMode:` to do any required state changes in the master view controller.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Have you tried changing the number of sections and the number of items per section corresponding to your controllerMode property, by any chance?

Comment: In -setControllerMode:, I used [UICollectionView performBatchUpdates:] to update the number of items and sections. I appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, in my app there are different numbers of sections in the two modes, although I use the more nuclear `-[UICollectionView reloadData]` to force a full update.

Comment: When using -[UICollectionView reloadData], were you able to animate layout changes? In which place do you call -[UICollectionView reloadData]? When calling this method in -setControllerMode:, I get an exception that states that the CollectionView has invalid number of sections, which is caused by different number returned as a number of sections in UICollectionViewDataSource.

Comment: I don't think you can animate if using `-[UICollectionView reloadData]` - because of the decoupling between view and model, the `UICollectionView` can't know which cells are new and which are old.

Comment: I am able to make transition animated by using performBatchUpdates Instead of using reloadData :)